# Making call to number mentioned in the text field

Tags: iphone, ios

I am doing a birthday Remainder application . In that i provided a textfield to enter a mobile /phone number. And bottom i provided a button in which if we press that button call need to be proceed to the number given in the text field.I tried but i am not able to do that.Can any one help me in coding.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try This One.

```
-(void) makeCall{
 NSString* phoneNumber=yourTextFiled.text;//TextFiled 
 NSString *phoneNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phoneNumber];
 NSURL* callUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNumber];
 //check  Call Function available only in iphone
 if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:callUrl]){

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:callUrl]];
 }
 else{
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ALERT" message:@"This function is only available on the iPhone"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
[alert show];
[alert release];
}    
}
```

I hope,it'll Really helpful to you.

Comment: You should not check if de device is an iPhone. You can just call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:]` method. If you call this method with a phonenumber URL it will return `NO` on devices that can't make calls.

Comment: @rckoenes yes you are right,but let me know if I follow that way(Check device and show alert according to the device).will it be wrong..?

Comment: Could be if Apple changes the device name or does not return the device name. But what if there is going to be an iPad that can make  calls?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self._phoneNumber]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

works only in iphone, must be implemented your own alert delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this 2 link:

calling number: 
[Programmatically Dial a Phone number and pass DTMF using the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584663/programatically-dial-a-phone-number-and-pass-dtmf-using-the-iphone-sdk)

and why not getting value from textfield:
[iPhone SDK: how to get the value of a UITextField in an alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204958/iphone-sdk-how-to-get-the-value-of-a-uitextfield-in-an-alert)